# How would I break down a chemical formula as a string so that my program can calculate the total AMU

Tags: javascript

So, I want to have my program auto calculate, for instance, how many water atoms are in 1 gram of water. I need it to break apart the formula, so again, using water, the program could assign variables to look like this:
var hydrogen = 2
var oxygen = 1

I have no clue how to make it so that my program can read the formula and assign it like that.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 align="center">Chemistry</h1>
  <h2 align="center">Mole Calculations</h2>
  <p>What is the element's formula?</p>
  <input type="text" id="formula" />
  <p>Are you converting to grams(g), miligrams(mg), pounds(lb), particles(amu), or moles(m)</p>
  <input type="text" id="convertingto" />
  <p>What measurement are you converting from? Use the same rules listed above.</p>
  <input type="text" id="convertingfrom" />
  <p>How much of the measurement above do you have of the element?</p>
  <input type="text" id="amountstart" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="getmoles">Get Values</button>
  <script>
  document.getElementById('getmoles').onclick = function() {
    var formula = document.getElementById('formula').value;
    var to = document.getElementById('convertingto').value;
    var from = document.getElementById('convertingfrom').value;
    var amount = document.getElementById('amountstart').value;
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want help parsing a formula represented as a string, maybe it would be more helpful to give an example of what that string looks like instead of a lot of HTML that doesn't help us understand the problem.

Comment: The following link points to a repo published on GitHub which has an example of parsing a string for a molecule into a JSON representation of its elements. https://github.com/pcorey/molecule-to-atoms